# background of picture in crystal report is different of the original

Tags: crystal-reports

I make report by using crystal report
and appear strange problem , the background of logo is gray although the background of original logo is white?? 
you can show the screenshot of the problem
[crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQxoj.png)

Comment: Easy option as per my knowledge is change the background of the report to grey

Comment: i want the background white :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> File -> Report Options -> Retain Original Image Color Depth.

Comment: i use report inside vs??

Comment: @AhmedRabie In VS there is similar option available.   Right click on report --> Report Option --> check the checkbox: Keep original Image Quality and Color Depth.